# Java EE 7: @Produces/@Inject preferred to @EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

Looking around StackOverflow I see [answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17842796/1270789) which suggest that `@Produces`/`@Inject` is the way to go unless one specifically needs a remote Bean. Furthermore, Adam Bien says [DAO is dead](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jpa_ejb3_killed_the_dao), so what is the "proper" EE 7 way to `@Inject` an EntityManager? Currently I have this kind of code:

```
@Path("/userdb")
public class UserDBInterface {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Transactional
    public String dbInteraction()
    {
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setLogin("ken");
        user1.setSalt(JpaSecurityUtils.getSalt());
        user1.setPassword(JpaSecurityUtils.hashPassword("password", user1.getSalt()));
        em.persist(user1);
        return "Created User DB";
    }
}
```

However, this gives me this error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.transaction.TransactionalException: Managed bean with Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRED encountered exception during commit javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.

Now, what the previous-referenced answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17842796/1270789) suggest a solution like:

```
public class Resource {
    @PersistenceContext
    @Produces
    EntityManager em;
}
```

I have actually placed that in my `@WebListener` implementation of `ServletContextListener`. Then my usage code becomes:

```
@Path("/userdb")
public class UserDBInterface {
    @Inject private EntityManager em;

    // ...etc as above
}
```

However, I now get an error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
>   1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=EntityManager,parent=UserDBInterface,qualifiers={}),position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1502799812)

If I delete the `@Transactional` the injection appears to work, but I get a:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

I'm sure I'm missing something simple!

Comment: In your specific example above you are seeing "Managed bean with Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRED encountered exception during commit" - can you edit your question with the details of this exception?

Comment: @NBW, I was using GlassFish 4.0 with JAX-RS 2.0, but I read that that was a bit buggy, so I upgraded to GF 4.0.1-b3 and JAX-RS 2.5, and I updated my code to just do a direct `@PersistenceContext EntityManager em;` and it appears to work. I'm still a beginner (and perhaps the tools are still immature too) so it always seems quite random as to what works or not.

Comment: Ken glad it worked for you. GF4 is up to promoted build 10 now so you might be interested in that. I ran into some issues with builds < 8. They are marching on to the 4.1 release around the time of JavaOne this fall so each promoted build gets better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam Bien is a proponent of the ECB (Entity, Control, Boundary) pattern with Java EE 7. In that case your boundary layer is your JAX-RS endpoint, it would not inject a PersistenceManager, but would inject a (most likely `@Stateless`) EJB (the Control layer). The EJB would have its PersistenceContext injected `@PersistenceContext`. The EJB itself would be injected into the JAX-RS endpoint with `@EJB`.

Comment: As noted in my comment for the main question, that was the solution I stumbled upon. There seemed to be hints that the JAX-RS and the CDI interfere with each other when used within the same class. Thanks for explaining Adam Bien's stance - I really should buy his book!

Comment: Personally I am not a fan of using CDI to inject PersistenceContexts - as things stand with Java EE 7 I prefer to use EJB 3.1 beans (they offer among other things richer transactional capabilities) for my controller classes. Java EE 8 will bring further parity between CDI and EJB. Another good resource are the [Java EE examples on github] (https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples)